# diff on folder in visual studio code

Tags: vs-code, visualstudiocode, diff

I am using `Visual Studio Code` with `Salesforce Extensions`.

I am trying to find all diffs between my local project and the sandbox.

When I right click on classes folder and click on `Diff Folder Against Org` is runs and then comes up with just 1 file when there are more than 10 files. When I run it on a single file it works.

I am not sure why it isn't working properly when I run it on the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The problem was that most of the files that had changes were not saved yet, so they didn't appear as different from the org code. As soon as I saved those files and ran it again, all the diffs appeared.